# Where to find the list of PyQt default local variables?

Tags: pyqt5

I have renamed "app" local variable in my PyQt example, and the whole thing stopped to work. It seems there is a default that the "app" variable holds the handler of the main window. Are there any docs describing other defaults like this?

This works:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = style.init()
    main = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This does not work:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    style.init()
    main = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I've added a generic answer to your question below — but for more specific help, you'll need to post your code!

Comment: Thanks, Martin! The code becomes too big to post. I've made grep for "app" entry, and it can be found only once. I believe there may be some "garbage collection" / "early destructor" mechanics behind my problem.

Comment: Oh. The last line :-)

Comment: Precisely ;) ...difficult to spot these things sometimes. Thanks for posting the code, I've updated my answer with the specifics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a 'default local variable' in Python, you can name anything however you like. The problem is likely caused by that variable `app` being defined/used elsewhere in your code — now you've changed the name, it is no longer clear what `app` (or your new name) refers to.

You can see this in your second code example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    style.init()
    main = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here, you are still calling `exec_()` on the `app` object, which (since you've removed the assignment to `app` from `style.init()`) now no longer exists).